# Creating link between SoftLayer Virtual Guest and Users to be notified for the Basic monitor

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have created a basic monitor for the Virtual Guest. Now trying to add the user to be notified via

POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer_Notification_Virtual_Guest.json
Content-Type: application/json

{"parameters":[{"guestId":29656047,"userId":12134}]}

Response is 200 OK. While the response body is

{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

The error doesn't tell me anything. In fact after some time I was able to figure out that the userId was wrong. Is the API behavior right?